# Parenthesis for English name(foreigner)

Tags: names, parentheses

I have an English name but that English name is not shown on my passport or birth certificate. However, I would like to be known by that English name. How should I show people that I would like to be know by that name?

For example, my legal name is Jia Wen Lee. If I want to be known by my English name, can I put my name as Jia Wen Lee(Jane) ?

Thanks for reading through and helping me!

Comment: We do see things like "Jin Wen (Jane) Lee"; I assume "Lee" is the surname, here.  And also the other way: "Jane (Jin Wen) Lee".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have "Jane" be treated as your first name, then it should be "Jia (Jane) Wen Lee". Note that there should be spaces around the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The Defacto standard used by newspapers in Hong Kong (where this comes up a lot!) is to simply put your Anglicised name first, without parenthesis.  English speakers will naturally read this as your first name without any confusion.

e.g. ["but that perception is not in line with the vision of Alibaba founder Jack Ma Yun - at least as far as his tech giant is concerned."](http://www.thestandard.com.hk/section-news.php?id=195522&story_id=50011560&con_type=1&d_str=20180509&sid=17)

and

[For Financial Secretary Paul Chan Mo-po, there couldn't be a worse piece of news.](http://www.thestandard.com.hk/section-news.php?id=195278&story_id=50011096&con_type=1&d_str=20180502&sid=17)